# Css order property doesn't update when set by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When updating an element's order property after it is on the dom rendered like so, the html elements fail to reorder.

```
$(".test").css('order', '0');
```

Is this a known issue?

Edit: Yes, the container has the following css properties:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
overflow-y: overlay;
overflow-x: hidden;
position: relative;
```

Edit: error demonstrated in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/me6g30ur/

My code:

```
$(".update").on("click", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $(".child").length; i++) {
      $(".child").css("order", Math.floor(Math.random * 100));
    }

  });
```

Comment: Are you sure it is wrapping in flex css? It worked for me when I just tested it

Comment: Are you using flexbox? Some context is needed here.

Comment: @isherwood Yes, check edit.

Comment: @HHHome can you put up example code in a snippet?

Comment: Maybe a jsfiddle or something (or an inline snippet) that you can show what doesnt work?

Comment: @Neal https://jsfiddle.net/me6g30ur/

Comment: Can you add that to your question? @HHHome

Comment: The problem is with your  `Math.floor(Math.random * 100)`

Comment: Nope, not a known problem. https://jsfiddle.net/sx6yarcg/ so clearly you have a logic problem. Do a better job of simplifying your code when trying to get to the bottom of a problem.

Comment: @HHHome You provided a fiddle. The edit merely includes the same code from the fiddle into your question. So I don't understand what's the point of this rollback war. You provided this code. If you were misunderstood and have gotten answers that do answer you question, but aren't what you intended, please open a new question, linking to this one, and explain *exactly* what you need different. Please include code samples and explanations *in the question body* along with any relevant links like jsfiddles.

Answer (score 0):

Two things wrong with your code (from your fiddle)

1. `Math.random` is a function so you need to do `Math.random()`
2. You need to choose the child element to update. You can use `:eq(index)` selector for that

Final code: https://jsfiddle.net/me6g30ur/3/

```
  $(".update").on("click", function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $(".child").length; i++) {
        var order = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      $(".child:eq(" + i + ")").css("order", order);
    }

  });
```

---

Side note:

Might be better to use jquery's `.each` loop instead of a for loop which would lead to less querying.

Then inside the loop you can do `this.style.order = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);`